# How to undo the latest change to localstorage while still retaining the old value?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am creating a clock where the hours and minutes for the alarm are inputted using ion range slider. The values for the hour and minutes are stored in local storage.

When I move the slider the value constantly changes however how do I go back to the previous stored value if the user clicks cancel?

I've looked into `storage.removeItem(keyName);` but that removes the value completely which I do not want.

Below is my codepen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mXYaQz

Function for storing values:

```
(function () { 
     from = 0;
     $to.prop("value", 0);
     if (localStorage.getItem("StoreMinutes"))  {
        $to.prop("value", localStorage.getItem("StoreMinutes"));
        from = $to.prop;
     }
})();
```

Comment: Just add another localStorage key value for previous value and update it accordingly.

Comment: How would I permanently store the previous value? The value is constantly changing whenever the user moves the slider so if they move the slider halfway and clicks cancel, it should go back to the value it was before which is not a fixed one.

Comment: Possibly change your design a little, have a button called set alarm, and when they click it, show them the slider, then have them either confirm or cancel. When they confirm their selection, set your localStorage key value for previous value, then use that to revert upon clicking Cancel.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot re arrange or add additional functionality as it is a provided design (base html is in the codepen). Is there not something I can do with the cancel button which is under the slider?

Comment: It looks to me after running your codepen fiddle, that the cancel button just cancels the action of setting the alarm, so it doesn't appear that it matters what they had previously selected.